# How to hide currency symbol in angular currency pipe

Tags: angular, number-formatting, angular-pipe, currency-pipe

I'm trying to use Angular `currency` pipe and I wanted to remove the currency symbol all together from the formatted number, but it seems there is no option to do that. So is there any easy way to achieve this without writing a custom pipe for it?

Comment: Maybe use this: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Comment: @R.Richards Oh, I was so lost in achieving this with `currency` pipe, I didn't pay attention to other pipes that would do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As @R.Richards mentioned, I ended up using the `number` pipe:

```
{{ 50000 | number }} <!-- output: 50,000 -->
```

Answer (score 41):

Just send the arguments empty:

```
price | currency:'':''
```

Comment: It won't work. The number gets formatted with the dollar sign!

Comment: Thanks, this works on me. This code is only remove the currency symbol

Answer (score 4):

Hope this example could help.

```
{{ 0001234.012 | currency:' ':'symbol':'0.0-1' }}  <!-- 1,234 -->
{{ 0001234.012 | currency:' ':'symbol':'0.1-1' }}  <!-- 1,234.0 -->
{{ 0001234.012 | currency:' ':'symbol':'0.0-2' }}  <!-- 1,234.01 -->
{{ 0001234.012 | currency:' ':'symbol':'0.2-2' }}  <!-- 1,234.01 -->

{{ 123 | currency:' ':'symbol':'5.0-0' }}          <!-- 00,123 -->
{{ 123 | currency:' ':'symbol':'4.0-0' }}          <!-- 0,123 -->
{{ 123 | currency:' ':'symbol':'3.0-0' }}          <!-- 123 -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set this globally:

```ts
import { DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, useValue: '' },
  ],
  ...
})
```

Example:

```
<div>{{ 20124.56789 | currency }}</div>   <!-- output: 20,124.57 -->
```