# Angular: currency pipe - currency symbol without number

Tags: angular, internationalization

Is there a way to get a currency symbol from currency pipe? I have this piece of code in template:

```
{{ '' | currency : 'symbol' }}
```

But this shows nothing.

**Note:** I don't want to use `getCurrencySymbol` method, because I want to use what currency pipe provides.

**Update**

Unlike [How to hide currency symbol in angular currency pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891796/how-to-hide-currency-symbol-in-angular-currency-pipe), I'was asking about how to show *only* the currency symbol. And found different solution than `currency` pipe - I would like to share it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the symbol, you could use the `slice` pipe to get the first character e.g.

```html
{{ 0 | currency | slice:0:1 }}
// $
```

There is also a utility function `getCurrencySymbol` - which is probably used internally by the currency pipe

```js
import { getCurrencySymbol } from '@angular/common';

getCurrencySymbol('GBP', 'narrow'); // £
```

Comment: Sounds well, but is there any "pure" way in a sense it uses only currency pipe functionality?

Comment: Use this ```{{ ' ' | number }}```

Comment: @KibéM.C ```InvalidPipeArgument: '  is not a number' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'```

Comment: @Drenai The ```slice``` solution does not work anyway, because e.g. ```£``` sign is shown before number, while ```€``` is shown after number.